# Does SharePoint Online support .MOV video files

Tags: video, sharepoint-online

I would like to create an Asset Library to store Drone photos and Videos in SP Online.  I've created a content type where parent content type is Video.  The name of the Content Type is **Drone Videos**.

I've added Drone Videos to the Content Type supported by the Asset Library, yet when I upload an .MOV file, I can't change the content type of the file to Drone Videos.  It does appear in the list of content types for the Library.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload .mov file into SharePoint Asset library, but it will be identified as **Image** by default, not **video**, so you cannot change its content type to Drone Videos.

And also if you click "New"->"Video" or "Drone Videos", it will show as the following.

[image]